# How do I add a gap between series in MsChart?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I have created a chart with following code:

```
ChartAmalkerd.Titles[0].Text = "xxxx";
        ChartAmalkerd.Series.Add("x");
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["x"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["x"]["PointWidth"] = (0.5).ToString();
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["x"].Points.AddY(10);
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["x"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        ChartAmalkerd.Series.Add("y");
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["y"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["y"].Points.AddY(20);
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["y"]["PointWidth"] = (0.5).ToString();
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["y"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        ChartAmalkerd.Series.Add("y");
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["z"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["z"].Points.AddY(20);
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["z"]["PointWidth"] = (0.5).ToString();
        ChartAmalkerd.Series["z"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

but the columns are together and there is no any gap between columns.
How do I add a gap between columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally come up with less hacky solutions, but as I have no time to research tonight - I at least have semi-solutions that might serve your purpose depending on your requirements, so I will give you something to start with.

What you are experiencing is the default mschart behavior if you do not set an X datapoint for this chart type.

If you never set an x for the points in a series each datapoint 'x' will be defined by the data point index position within its series + 1.  You are using three series, each with one data point, so in your example all points are set to an x value of 1 automatically.

Based on this, each column above will be squeezing in to be drawn as close to their automatically generated x value as possible, which in this case, all points are x = 1.

There may be a better workaround, however, one solution to this would be to assign an x value with an offset based on the number of series/data points you plan on using.

If you know you are going to have three series you can add apply a unique offset for each series

For example

```
chart1.Series["x"].Points.AddXY(chart1.Series["x"].Points.Count + 1 - 0.05, yValue);
chart1.Series["y"].Points.AddXY(chart1.Series["y"].Points.Count + 1, yValue);
chart1.Series["z"].Points.AddXY(chart1.Series["z"].Points.Count + 1 + 0.05, yValue);
```

NOTICE:  You will discover interesting 'bugs'/features if you do not add the '+ 1' to the datapoint count for series "y" above.  Without it, the first data point of series 'y' will be zero.  When you leave things at zero, microsoft charting will assume you have not set anything and use a default behavior.

Another hacky workaround is less pretty if you are using grid lines, but it will work.

Use your original code, but add white borders!
i.e. add this to each series (or perhaps just the center series)

```
chart1.Series["y"].BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series["y"].BorderColor = Color.White;
```

The workaround code examples I cite are tailored to your code sample above, which has  three series, each with one data point, but can be adapted for more series and more data points per series to make it more dynamic.  Let me know if you need help with such a task and I will try to get you going.

I will return and edit this answer later if I have time to research a less hacky answer this weekend.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
chart1.Series["y"].BorderWidth = 2;
chart1.Series["y"].BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
```

works nicely.

Comment: If, as seems likely, this is a derivative of the other answer, it would only be polite to indicate that with a direct link to it from the Share link under that answer.

Comment: I did add a comment that it was only an extension of the answers posted above but it was removed from my post. Also i did post this as answer only because i could not add comments then. I picked transparent color from ms visual suggestions list and it worked..

Comment: You included a note about how it [wasn't an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346454/if-the-author-says-its-not-an-answer-can-we-take-their-word-for-it) -- but it was, so I took it out. You *didn't* mention anything about it being an extension, or of what, which you should have.

Comment: Well you are tottaly wrong. I did say that i wanted to add this as an comment to the answer above but could not due to not being able to add comments.

Comment: "could not add a comment" is far too ambiguous; it can and usually does imply "… to the question".